# Postgresql binary column free memory

Tags: postgresql, binary

we have a database which we store some small files temporarily before they are pushed to S3. The problem I'm having at the moment is that once we clear the biniary in Postgresql (setting the binary column value = null) it does not seem to free up the memory. Are we missing anything?

Comment: The number of rows doesn't change; the number of columns doesn't change: why would you expect the table to change its size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to perform a `vacuum full` in order to reclaim the free space, or just a `vacuum` to be able to re-use the space.
The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) says:

> Plain VACUUM (without FULL) simply reclaims space and makes it
>   available for re-use. This form of the command can operate in parallel
>   with normal reading and writing of the table, as an exclusive lock is
>   not obtained. However, extra space is not returned to the operating
>   system (in most cases); it's just kept available for re-use within the
>   same table. VACUUM FULL rewrites the entire contents of the table into
>   a new disk file with no extra space, allowing unused space to be
>   returned to the operating system. This form is much slower and
>   requires an exclusive lock on each table while it is being processed.

Let's emphasis that this is true for both `delete` or `update` commands.

> The FULL option is not recommended for routine use, but might be
>   useful in special cases. An example is when you have deleted or
>   updated most of the rows in a table and would like the table to
>   physically shrink to occupy less disk space and allow faster table
>   scans. VACUUM FULL will usually shrink the table more than a plain
>   VACUUM would.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, especially your explanation on full vacuum. The box is the instance on AWS RDS and we thought the routine vacumn would do it. I'll see if we can schedule a full vacumn. Can I ask you another question, RDS say that for best performance, it the machine need to have enough Memory to hold the whole DB. does this affect that or not really? Thanks